# Return Comparator's compare method using a double?

Tags: java, compare

So I have a class to compare the rating of a film. It implements the comparator class as seen below:

```
public class FilmComparator implements Comparator<Film> {

private Map<Film, List<Rating>> ratings;

public FilmComparator(Map<Film, List<Rating>> ratings) {
    this.ratings = ratings;
}

@Override
public int compare(Film o1, Film o2) {
    double average1 = average(o1);
    double average2 = average(o2);
    return average2 - average1; // I cant do this because it need to return an int
}

private double average(Film f) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Rating r : ratings.get(f)) {
        sum += r.getValue();
    }
    return sum / ratings.get(f).size();
}
}
```

As you can see, the average might not always be an integer. I am wondering how I would be able to have a more accurate compare. For example, I am having issues when the average returns 3.6 for one object but 3.0 for the other. To the compare method, the are the same but I need to show a difference. Is this possible?

Comment: *"the average might not always be an integer"*: [Division of integers in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/7220681)

Comment: maybe beneficial to calculate and store the `average` on creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, let Double do the work for you. Do

```
return Double.compare(average1, average2); // or swap if desired
```

Comment: @yasgur99: no, you just aren't as familiar with the API, but that is changing.

Comment: @yasgur99: you don't own a farm near Woodstock, NY, by chance do you?

Comment: you are the first person to ever wonder if I am indeed related to max

Comment: my username is a refrence to the yasgur farm you are thinking of, but I am not related in any way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129179/discussion-between-yasgur99-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).